# How to apply rendering to child items

Tags: experience-editor, presentation, mvc

Assume I have a menu with menu sections.

The menu has a title, opening paragraph, and a list of menu sections.

```
content
    title - Single line text
    paragraph - Rich text
    sections - Multilist
```

A menu section might be: Burgers, Pasta, Pizza.

I have a Model controller for the Menu.

The Model is just a copy of the fields in the Sitecore item:

```
  public string Title
  public string Paragraph
  public Item[] Sections
```

Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<div>@Model.Paragraph</div>
<hr />
@foreach (var section in Model.Sections)
{
  // how do I apply a rendering to a Sitecore item (id)?
}
```

And of course I would like to add / move / remove / modify Sections in the Experience Editor.

Rolan

Comment: Change your architecture, remove the multilist, add a placeholder where you want the sections to go, create a `Section` component and allow the content editor to add them in via the Experience Editor.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to add rendering to section item programmatically? Can you provide more detail here what you want achieve by doing this? may be someone can suggest more easy way to handle your requirement... any screenshot also if you have?

Comment: @RichardSeal If i remove the multilist, then what is the point of a multilist?  I wanted the Menu item to know what sections it has, so maybe it could be used somewhere else, with its sections intact.

Comment: There are many reasons to use a multilist. Just not the use case you have I think.

Comment: I agree.  Simpler objects that don't need a whole rendering.  Very new at this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done like this:

```
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<div>@Model.Paragraph</div>
<hr />
@foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item section in Model.Sections)
{
    @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/MySectionsRendering", new
    {
        DataSource = section.ID
    });
}
```

**Side note**: I do encourage you to work with placeholders in your Layout.cshtml and then adding the above code to a separate Rendering which is bound to the placeholder via standard values.